# In python how do i divide variables in a list by a float?

Tags: python-3.x

### code to convert euros to pounds and display in table

```
def exchangeTable():
    
    for i in range [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]:
        exchangeRate = 1.15
        pounds = i//exchangeRate
        print(i,pounds)
```

Comment: If you want float division (`/`), why are you explicitly using integer division (`//`)?

Comment: And use `range(1, 21)` instead of `range [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]`.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py that or they don't mean to have `range` in there at all :)

Comment: @JonClements It's actually a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the code you want:

```
def exchangeTable(euro_range):
    if euro_range < 0:
        raise Exception('Received negative range: {0}'.format(euro_range))
    if euro_range == 0:
        print('0 euros = 0 pounds')
        return
    exchange_rate = 1.15
    pounds = 1 / exchange_rate
    print ('1 euro = {0} pound'.format(pounds))
    if euro_range > 1:
        for i in range(2, euro_range + 1):
            pounds = i / exchange_rate
            print('{0} euros = {1} pounds'.format(i, pounds))
```

Answer (score 0):

ive done it guys thanks for your help all heres my answer:

def exchangeTable():

```
for i in range (0,21):
    exchangeRate = 1.15
    pounds = i/exchangeRate
    print(i,"euros = ","{0:0.2f} pounds".format(pounds))
```